# Get rows added to database table within the last 24 hours

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `create_date` *(btw, this column is a varchar)* column in my table `products` I am using codeigniter, so I communicate with the table like so:

```
function get_recent_products()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('create_date' => date('y-d-m')));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Using the above function, I want to be able to only pull rows from the table that where added within the last 24 hours. The system stores the date as: `2014-02-28`

Please help me out with this!

Comment: You can't get data for last 24 hours unless you have the timestamp in the DB.

Comment: You can't query by date unless you have a date field.  You can't query by date and/or time unless you have a datetime field.  Q: Are you saving the creation date as a datetime value?  Read this article [Difference between MySQL Date, DateTime and Timestamp values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @AkshatSinghal I would assume he does, since it's checking for `create_date`

Comment: @AkshatSinghal Okay, I changed the `create_date` to a `timestamp` rather than `varchar`

Comment: I'd actually recommend "datetime" instead of timestamp.  Here's a sample query (SQL): `SELECT * FROM news WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original column type for `check_date` use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD COLUMN `check_date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

UPDATE TABLE `table_name`
SET `check_date_time` = `create_date` LIMIT 9999999999999999;
```

from there you should be able to call from the last day and you can start filling in this field to generate times going forward :)

Comment: Not understanding how that is getting me the last 24 hour's additions. I need what I actually put in PHP

Comment: This did not find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately because you weren't tracking times in your database, there's not a whole lot you can do, at least with this you can start tracking it and you can pull up things that happened today and yesterday to kind of cross reference for 24 hours :/

Answer (score 0):

If the date is stored in a varchar column as `2014-02-28`, then you want to use the following format for the [`date()`](http://php.net/function.date.php) function:

```
date('Y-m-d')
```

Note that case is important. The format you used `date('y-d-m')` would give you `14-28-02`.

You'll also need to pass an appropriate timestamp to the `date()` function. The default is the value of [`time()`](http://php.net/function.time.php).

If you want to select records for the last 24 hours as opposed to on a specific day, you will need to store the time as well. I'd recommend using a `datetime` column to store both the date and time in one field. This gives you the ability to do a lot of date and time calculations directly in your SQL statements.